# convert decimal to hexidecimal 2 digits at a time Ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, decimal

I am trying to convert a string of decimal values to hex, grabbing two digits at a time

so for example, if i were to convert these decimals two digits at a time

```
01 67 15 06 01 76 61 73
```

this would be my result

```
01430F06014C3D49
```

i know that `str.to_s(16)` will convert decimal to hex but like i said I need this done two digits at a time so the output is correct, and i have no clue how to do this in Ruby

here is what i have tried

```
str.upcase.chars.each_slice(2).to_s.(16).join
```

Comment: Is your input "01 67 15 06 01 76 61 73"? or "0167150601766173"?

Comment: This is confusing because you have not displayed your input and output as Ruby objects. For example, if `01 67 15 06 01 76 61 73` and `01430F06014C3D49` are meant to be strings you should include quotes: `"01 67 15 06 01 76 61 73"` and `"01430F06014C3D49"`.

Comment: `str.upcase…` – what is `str`? If it contains only digits, why would you upcase them?

Comment: Also, `#each_slice` is likely working on arrays of strings. Converting those to a string will not yield the desired behavior. Calling `#to_s` with an integer argument won't work at all in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression and [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format):

```
"01 67 15 06 01 76 61   73".gsub(/\d{2} */) { |s| sprintf("%02x", s.to_i) } 
  #=> "01430f06014c3d49"
```

The regular expression `/\d{2} */)` matches two digits followed by zero or more spaces (note `73` is not followed by space).

The result of the block calculation replaces the two or three characters that were matched by the regular expression.

`sprintf`'s formatting directive forms a sting containing `2` characters, padded to the left with `'0'`'s, if necessary, and converting the string representation of an integer in base 10 to the string representation of an integer in base 16 (`'x'`).

Alternatively, one could use [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-25) (with `sprintf`'s formatting directives):

```
"01 67 15 06 01 76 61   73".gsub(/\d{2} */) { |s| "%02x" % s.to_i } 
  #=> "01430f06014c3d49"
```

Comment: Alternatively, the regular expression doesn't need the grouping.  `"01 67 1506 01 76 61 73".gsub(/\d{2} ?/) { |x| sprintf("%02x", x) }`

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, I wasn't aware of that. It's an improvement so I've edited my answer.

Comment: The only other improvement that might be made (but doesn't have to be given the way the problem is specified would be to allow for zero or more of any type of whitespace character matched in the regex.  E.g. `"01 67 1506 01 76 61 73".gsub(/ \d{2} \s* /x) { |x| sprintf("%02x", x) }`

Comment: Your code raises an `ArgumentError` for `"08"` and `"09"` because they are treated as octal numbers. `s.to_i` would fix that.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. Dumb mistake.